# Have no spaces between bars in matplotlib bar graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want my resulting graph to look like a histogram, with no space at all between bars. I am using matplotlib's axes.bar(). I've looked through the documentation and nothing I tried from there helped (setting pad=0, setting xticks). I want each bar to have width=0.1, since that is the size of the interval between ticks, and I want to completely fill the graph.

Here is my code

```
colors = self.data[index].colors # a list of the color each bar should have
depth = self.data[index].depth # the depth in meters, increases by set interval (0.1)
data = np.ones(len(cluster_labels))
axis.bar(x=depth, height=data, color=colors, width=0.1, align='edge')
axis.tick_params(axis='x', pad=0)
axis.get_xaxis().set_visible(True)
axis.get_yaxis().set_visible(True)
axis.set_xlim(xmin=self.ruler_pix_to_m(idx_begin), xmax=self.ruler_pix_to_m(idx_end))
axis.set_ylim(ymin=0, ymax=1)
axis.set_axis_on()
```

The graph I am getting is: 
[image]

What I want is a graph where all I can see is the bars, from tick 2.2 to tick 16.78, like below:

[image]

How do I specify to have no space at all between the bars? Is there another way to get the type of plot I want if a matplotlib bar graph doesn't work? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Update: I got rid of my secondary axis and changed the width = 1, now here is what the graph looks like:

[image]

however, I don't want the white space at the ends of the graph, but trying to use .set_xlim(xmin=x_start, xmax=x_end) results in the following:

[image]

As you can see, the x axis gets completely messed up the x limits that im using are the first and last data points in the bar graph x axis, so I am not sure what's causing the range to get so small.

Comment: Since you seem to be new to Stack Overflow, you should read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You seem to have 2 x-axes. And you seem to be specifying the widths via the axis coordinates of the top axis. For that axis you need width=1. The shown output doesn't seem to come from the shown code. By the way, you can hide the ticks with `axis.tick_params(axis='x', length=0)`. If the bar height is constant, it would be more readable to just write `axis.bar(..., height=1, ...)`.

Comment: Hi JohanC, thank you very much for your reply, my second axis is a secondary axis that I added, can you explain what you mean by needing width=1 for that axis? Additionally, I will try providing a runnable example.

Comment: since this code is part of a much larger snippet, I don't know how to plot the matplotlib.figure.Figure object to exactly reproduce this (I am showing the Figure in a tkinter canvas) Is there much of a difference between matplotlib.figure.Figure() and matplotlib.pyplot ?

Comment: Well, just set the width to 0 in the call to bar. Your axis.bar has been drawn with axis being the top axis.

Comment: Hi Johan, I removed the secondary axis, and changed the width, you can see what the graph looks like now in my update above. The problem is now the white space, which Im having problems getting rid of using xlim

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a histogram using matplotlib you should probably utilize plt.hist(), if you specify the argument rwidth to be 1.0, the resulting graph will have no vertical gaps between bars.

Comment: I cannot use .hist() since I want each bar to have a different color, I tried width=1 but I want the bottom axis to match up with the top one (they should be the same), to my understanding, width=1 would make the bar take an interval of 1, but I want an interval of 0.1